# "No lines to end" issue with itemize inside a macro

Tags: macros, enumerate

```tex
\newcounter{question}[section]
\setlength{\parindent}{24pt}
\newcommand{\question}[2]{\noindent\textbf{\thesubsection(\thequestion)} -- \textsl{#1}\\[0.2cm]}\indent#2\stepcounter{question}}
```

I wrote this macro to answer questions in homeworks but I have an issue when `#1`  ends with an `enumerate` (or other list environments) environment (there is no line to end).

**My workaround is to put a `~` after the `\end{enumerate}` but this create a really wide space. I want to be able to end `#1` with an itemize-like environnement. Is there an other solution ?**

Here is a MWE :

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% Macro
\newcounter{question}[section]
\setlength{\parindent}{24pt}
\newcommand{\question}[2]{\noindent\textbf{\thesubsection(\thequestion)} -- \textsl{#1}\\[0.2cm]}\indent#2\stepcounter{question}}
\begin{document}
\question{A very nice question with a list :
\begin{enumerate}
\item an item !
\end{enumerate}~}{A very interesting answer}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markup you have here is .. somewhat weird but the error coms from  `\\`  in `\textsl{#1}\\[0.2cm]}`  you can not have `\\`  if `#1` ends in vertical mode (eg end of paragraph or end of list replace it by `\par\addvspace{0.2cm}` so it ends the paragraph and adds .2cm of space unless a larger space has already been added.

Comment: Indeed I deleted the `\textsl` which produces nothing with the font I'm using. Thank you for you answer